# Semantic-UI sticky tab menu bug

Tags: semantic-ui

It only takes in consideration the height of the first tab and for the rest of the tabs it automatically sticks the content to the bottom.

```
<div class="ui grid railContainer">

  <div class="four wide column ">

<div class="ui vertical fluid tabular menu sticky railMenu">
  <a class="item active" data-tab="first">
    TAB 1
  </a>
  <a class="item" data-tab="second">
    TAB 2
  </a>
  <a class="item" data-tab="third">
    TAB 3
  </a>
</div>

</div>

<div class="twelve wide stretched column" id="railContent">

 <div class="ui basic tab active" data-tab="first">
  <p>BEGIN tab 1</p>
  <div class="height"></div>
  <p>END</p>
</div>
<div class="ui basic tab" data-tab="second">
  <p>BEGIN tab 2</p>
  <div class="height first"></div>
  <p>it only sticks for the first height</p>
  <div class="height"></div>
  <p>END</p>
</div>
<div class="ui basic tab" data-tab="third">
  <p>BEGIN tab 3</p>
  <div class="height"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="height"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="height"></div>
  <p>END</p>
</div>
```

Here i called the tab

```
$('.menu .item')
  .tab()
;
```

Here i initialize ui sticky

```
$('.ui.sticky')
  .sticky({
    context: '#railContent',
    observeChanges: true,
  })
  .sticky('refresh')
;
```

Here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/efpyhqq9/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue, based on your try I came with a solution, refresh the sticky every time a tab end the loading and become fully visible.

```
$('.ui.sticky').sticky({
  context: '.railContent',
});

$('.menu .item').tab({
  onVisible() {
    $('.ui.sticky').sticky('refresh');
  }
});
```

I've forked your fiddle with this solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/arthurvasconcelos/pmyg0yL0/

Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since your **tab** contents don't have the same height, you need to refresh your **rail** every time your tab content is loaded. Below is a sample code that works for your situation.

```js
$('.menu .item').tab({
    onLoad: function(){
         $('.ui.sticky').sticky('refresh');
    }
});


$('.ui.sticky')
   .sticky({
     context: '.railContent',
}).sticky('refresh');
```

```css
.height {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 1000px;
}

.height.first {
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 1000px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.js"></script>

<div class="ui grid railContainer">

  <div class="four wide column ">
  
    <div class="ui vertical fluid tabular menu sticky railMenu">
      <a class="item active" data-tab="first">
        TAB 1
      </a>
      <a class="item" data-tab="second">
        TAB 2
      </a>
      <a class="item" data-tab="third">
        TAB 3
      </a>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="twelve wide stretched column railContent">
  
    <div class="ui basic tab active" data-tab="first">
      <p>BEGIN</p>
      <p>works only for first tab</p>
      <div class="height first"></div>
      <p>END</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ui basic tab" data-tab="second">
      <p>BEGIN</p>
      <p><i class="green check icon"></i>now it works for this one</p>
      <div class="height first"></div>
      <p>it only sticks for the first height</p>
      <div class="height"></div>
      <p>END</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ui basic tab" data-tab="third">
      <p>BEGIN</p>
      <p><i class="green check icon"></i>same for this one</p>
      <div class="height"></div>
      <br>
      <div class="height"></div>
      <br>
      <div class="height"></div>
      <p>END</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>

</div>
```

Note: This is also true to **visibility** where a refresh is needed every time the DOM height is changed dynamically.